# How to derive from a method if only the name changed?

Tags: c#

So

I have a base class like this:

```
 public abstract class Car
    {      

        protected static bool _on { get; set; }
        public abstract void Drive();
}
```

and a derived class like this:

```
 public class Renault: Car
    {      

        public override void Drive()
        {
            if (!_on)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Drive renault");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Have to start renault first");
            }
        }
```

and other derived class:

```
 public class Porsche :Car
    {
        public override void Drive()
        {            

            if (_on)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Drive Porsche");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Have to start Porsche first");
            }

        }      
    }
```

But you see the method implementation is almost the same, just the name differs.

So I made this helper class:

```
public  class HelperClass
    {

        protected  bool _on;

        public void Drive(string name)
        {

            if (_on)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Drive {name}");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Have to start {name} first");
            }

        }
    }
```

But how to use the HelperClass now? so that you just can say, in de derived(for example Porsche) class _on = true and that you then get the message:Drive Porsche

and if _on = false, that you will see the message: Have to start Porsche first.

Thank you

oke,

I added this:

```
 public class Person
    {
        private Car _car;       
        public Person(Car car)
        {
            this._car = car;
        }
        public void Drive() 
        {          

            this._car.Drive();
        }
    }
```

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Ford ford = new Ford();
            Person person = new Person(ford);
            person.Drive();
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

But then how manage that for example the porsche has the message: Have to start Porsche first, and for example the ford, has to get the message: Drive Ford. Because now the

```
 protected bool _on { get; set; }
```

sits in the base class

Comment: Note that `_on` being static seems like a very odd decision to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Introduce a protected `Name` property and move the implementation of `Drive()` to the base class. You seem to have the logic for `Drive()` reversed though. Shouldn't it allow you to drive when `_on` is true?

Check this example:

```
public abstract class Car
{
    protected bool _on { get; set; }

    protected virtual string CarName { get; }

    // For demonstration
    public void StartCar() => _on = true;
    public void StopCar() => _on = false;

    public void Drive()
    {
        if (_on)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Drive {CarName}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Have to start {CarName} first");
        }
    }
}

public class Renault : Car
{
    protected override string CarName { get => "Renault"; }
}

public class Porsche : Car
{
    protected override string CarName { get => "Porsche "; }
}
```

**Usage:**

```
var renault = new Renault();
renault.Drive();    // Car not started --> _on = false.

var porsche = new Porsche();
porsche.StartCar();
porsche.Drive();   // Car started --> _on = true.
```

**Output:**

```
Have to start Renault first
Drive Porsche
```

Comment: ah, oke, I see you updated the post. Yes, this is very nice. Thank you

Comment: But what do you mean with this:  // For demonstration
    public void StartCar() => _on = true;
    public void StopCar() => _on = false;

Comment: Of course would be nice to do that in the derived class

Comment: @savantTheCoder Those are just two simple methods I added to start/stop the car since you didn't have any way to do so. They're only for demonstration because I suspect you might want to have different logic. So, feel free to implement them differently (if you haven't already) and/or have different implementation for each derived class (since `_on` is `protected` and, therefore, accessible in derived classes).

Answer (score 2):

You don´t need any helper-class and you still don´t have any duplicated code if you extract the **common** things, and override what is different - in your case just the car's type. In fact you don´t even need multiple classes, as the cars name is just the name of the class. So this is enough:

```
public abstract class Car
{      
    private bool _on { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; }

    public Car(string model) { this.Model = model; }

    public void Drive()
    {            
        if (_on)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Drive { Model }");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Have to start { Model } first");
        }
    }      
}
```

Then you can create a `Porsche` like this:

```
var p = new Car("Porsche");
p.Drive();
```

Comment: oke, thank you. But of course I want to keep the class name, of the type of car

Answer (score 1):

You basically have the same code in both derived classes.  Assuming this will be the same in all derived classes then you can move this to the base class and then display the name of the class.

```
public abstract class Car
{
   protected static bool _on { get; set; }  
   public void Drive()
   {
       if (!_on)
       {
           Console.WriteLine($"Drive {this.GetType().Name}");
       }
       else
       {
           Console.WriteLine($"Have to start {this.GetType().Name} first");
       }
   }
}
```

BTW:  Are you sure that ! _on should allow you to drive?  Seem to be that the logic here is the wrong way around.
Also, as per the comments, I'm not sure that _on should be static.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
public abstract class Car
{
    protected static bool _on { get; set; }
    public virtual void Drive()
    {
        if (_on)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Drive {this.GetType().Name}");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"Have to start {this.GetType().Name} first");
        }        
    }
}

public class Porsche : Car
{

}

public class Renault : Car
{

}
```

Client code:

```
var porsche = new Porsche();
porsche.Drive();

var renault = new Renault();
renault.Drive();
```